# Vue.js - If I have the same route in Vue-router and in the back-end, Who responds first?

Tags: http, vue.js

Let's imagine I have a test.com serving a SPA domain with a route /home and a back-end that serves this SPA which also has a route called /home. Who answers first if I put test.com/home on my address bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the server responds first.

What you have to understand about routing in SPA's is that the routing is "faked". As in changing from one route to another doesn't cause the browser to make any HTTP requests like in a typical server-side application.

When you put `test.com/home` into your address bar for the first time the browser will make an HTTP GET request which makes its way into your server-side application returning the `index.html` file containing everything needed to bootstrap your SPA in the browser.

Once your SPA is running it's essentially hijacking your browsers' default behaviour which would be to send a GET request when you visit `test.com/home`. So if your app ever redirects the user back to `test.com/home` the browser would not send another GET request to your server, but instead the SPA would handle the routing and render the corresponding view.